# Previous preparation error: The developer disk image could not be mounted on this device

Tags: ios, xcode15

I'm currently using Xcode 15 (15A240d) and iOS 17.0.3
When trying to connect my iOS device, I get this error message:

[image]

This started to happen with my company iPhone when I upgraded to iOS17 and it was working fine with my personal phone. Af first glance I though it happen because it's a managed device, as it looked like a permission issue related with the latest iOS/Xcode versions.
But now, it just started to happen in my personal device also... so currently I'm not able to run to any of my devices.  Also this is also happening to some of my co-workers, and it's really a annoying situation.

I did not see anything recent regarding this issue on google, so if anyone was some clue on this it would be really appreciated!!

The only post i'm able to find related with this issue is this one:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/738712

I've tried all the things here, but I'm still stuck on the same place

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

The workaround may work, but I got back to the same point after a few days

---

Managed to get a workaround working for this, as Xcode15.1 and iOS 17.1 will be out next week, and hopefully it will fix this situation.

For the workaround:

- install xcode15.0.x and make sure it's running you app to the simulator
- download xcode14.3.1 from apple developer
- enable CoreDevice `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTEnableCoreDevice enabled`
- connect the phone to the mac, open Xcode14

You should have something similar to this in your simulator and devices:

[image]

There are 2 connected devices, and you should be able to build your app to the CoreDevice one, using Xcode14

*P.S. - If this does not work for you try to erase all content and settings and connect again to Xcode14*